# UITabBar View not opening - selected index

Tags: ios, mobile

I have a login screen after which home screen is shown. In home screen ,there are four buttons **a,b,c,d.** On pressing each button, say view **a,b,c,d** should appear related to view controller **a,b,c,d.** All these views are embedded in a UITabBar controller. The problem now is when I use the code

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

nothing happens and no view appears. How do i open the view using selected index method or any other method?
Thank You

Comment: I am unable to know, where are you going wrong, please share the code you are using that provides view controller to tabbarcontroller.

Comment: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2] from inside the CustomTab class itself.so replace to [self setSelectedIndex:2];

Comment: Have you changed root view controller to self.tabBarController?

Comment: My root view controller is my login page no!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally. Instead of

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Use

```
UITabBarController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierFromStoryboard"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
[controller setSelectedIndex:2];
```

This would work fine.